# Add event ticket to Apple wallet?

Tags: ios, swift, wallet, passkit

I am developing event app, in which, once user done with booking event ticket then, we have to add that pass to Apple wallet.

I am following below link to design my pass, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html

But the problem is I have completed the JSON, but how can I add ticket to wallet using code.

Comment: What exactly did you do? Did you use `PKAddPassesViewController ` ?

Comment: We just want to add our event ticket to Apple wallet . we generate ticket for our event from our app , now i  want to show that ticke into apple wallet

Comment: Where is your code? Please post related codes in your question.

Comment: i am not able to find the code for genrating the pass for apple wallet . How to generate `YOUR_PASS_NAME.pkpass`  ??

Comment: Is it mandatory the signature? How can I get a valid key/cer pair?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow the steps described in the Apple documentation:

- Create a directory structure, containing the `pass.json` file, images etc.
- Create an SHA-1 hash of every file and store it in `manifest.json` on top-level
- ZIP the contents of the directory
- Distribute the file using `application/vnd.apple.pkpass` MIME type

Once you get the file into your application:

- Read the file (e.g. using `Data(contentsOf:)`)
- Hand it into `PKPass(data:)`
- Present the pass to the `PKAddPassesViewController`